# Error de permiso denegado al obtener la ubicación en el sitio de Producción en google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, geolocalización, gps

junto con saludarle, quería ver si existe la posibilidad de que alguien me ayudara a resolver el siguiente problema:

Resulta que con un codigo de javascript obtengo la ubicación, y probandolo desde localhost funciona correctamente en todos los navegadores, pero cuando lo publico en el servidor o sitio de producción, me sale error, que el permiso ha sido denegado, pero esto solo ocurre en **Google Chrome**, ya en Internet Explorer me funciona en producción. El código es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var nav = null; 

    function requestPosition() {
        if (nav == null) {
            nav = window.navigator;
        }

        var geoloc = nav.geolocation;
        if (geoloc != null) {
            geoloc.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
        }

    }

    function successCallback(position) {
        document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = 
            position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = 
            position.coords.longitude;

    }

    function errorCallback(error) {
        var strMessage = "";

        // Check for known errors
        switch (error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                strMessage = "Access to your location is turned off. "  +
                    "Change your settings to turn it back on.";
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                strMessage = "Data from location services is " + 
                    "currently unavailable.";
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                strMessage = "Location could not be determined " +
                    "within a specified timeout period.";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = strMessage;
    }

</script>

        <label for="latitude">Latitude: </label> <div id="latitude"></div><br />
        <label for="longitude">Longitude: </label> <div id="longitude"> </div><br />
        <div id="status"> </div><br />
        <input type="button" onclick="requestPosition()" value="Get Latitude and Longitude"  />
```

Cuando está en el sitio de producción, el error pasa por la linea de validación del **CASE error.PERMISSION_DENIED:**

No se porque motivo me funciona en localhost, pero cuando está en el sitio web, da ese error.
Si alguien tiene alguna idea, desde ya se lo agradecería, me imagino que alguna parte habrá que habilitar algun permiso, pero lo lógico debería ser desde el cliente, y no desde el servidor, ya que yo deseo obtener la ubicación del cliente, de cualquier parte donde me pueda encontrar.

Observación:
Al inspeccionar en la consola del navegador me dice el siguiente error en la funcion:  eoloc.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback)

getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

Comment: donde veo eso, si fuera valido, en que implicaría eso?parece que me obliga que sea https y no http

Comment: No tiene ssl valido, This page is not secure. Que hay que hacer?, hay que comprar algun certificado para tener https? o algo así?

Comment: es gratis, ahora necesitaría averiguar como se hace toda la gestion

Comment: gracias @RubenHernandez

Comment: @RubenHernandez, de casualidad tienes algun tutorial o link que indique como hacerlo, la verdad es que nunca lo he hecho

Comment: Muchas gracias @RubenHernandez, en este caso que opciones de la combobox debería elegir para instalar en un servidor de windows server con mysql?

Comment: @RubenHernandez, pero el certificado que se genera sirve para windows server?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82916/discussion-between-danilo-and-ruben-hernandez).

Comment: @RubenHernandez, habilite un chat en donde te hice dos preguntas,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hace algún tiempo que Google ya no permite hacer uso de sus herramientas mediante conexiones `HTTP`, requieren que instales y configures en tu servidor un certificado `SSL` valido

Para comprobar si el sitio cuenta con alguno puedes ir a la consola de Chrome y buscar esta pestaña

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todos los accesos debera ser con

> HTTPS

Mas Info https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Puedes implementar en un servidor un certificado gratuito con

https://letsencrypt.org/

Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, tenía ese problema y es que la configuración de la pagina por el navegador, te genera un caché así que lo que debes hacer es borrar el caché o no permitir que la página lo genere.

Para ello debes escribir el siguiente código en el html de la página donde estés ejecutando la geolocalización, debes poner el código en medio del head osea: <*head>INSERTAR AQUÍ<*/head>, donde dice insertar aquí allí viene el siguiente código:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

    <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
    
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
    
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Y listo, con eso ya puedes ejecutar la geolocalización desde el localhost